# Conditional model calling joomla

Tags: php, joomla

How can I activate joomla model just on called layout. I have the following url structure

```
/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view&layout=edit&id=3
```

if `layout=edit` model should be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling this:

```
/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=my_view.edit&id=3
```

Comment: This code will call function "edit" of the controller "my_view". If the task variable contains a dot (.), it assumes that this variable is in the form of controller.task or controller.method. http://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview

Comment: thank you for the feedback both of you, yes I just want to give a try with this url structure seems to be promising

Answer (score 1):

Check the layout in your view:

```
if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->getWord('layout') == 'edit')
{
  // call your model here
}
```

[Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)